# ADSB DF17 Altitude decoding

Tags: altitude, ads-b

I develop ADSB DF17 messages decoding device.
I see that barometric height decoding differs between documents, describing the encoding standard:

1. https://mode-s.org/decode/content/ads-b/3-airborne-position.html
   Section 5.1.

N is 11 bit binary number with Q bit extracted.
When Q bit is 1, then formula is

> 25 * N - 1000 [ft]

When Q bit is 1. then formula is vaguely described, data is Gray-coded, I suppose it is:

> 100 * decodeGray(N) - 1000 [ft]

2. http://airmetar.main.jp/radio/ADS-B%20Decoding%20Guide.pdf

There is nothing about the Gray encoding, it just states, that Q bit determines which encoding factor is used (25x or 100x)

When it comes to available libraries it is getting even weirder.

- pyModeS -> when Q is 1, then everything is clear, when Q is 0, results from pyModeS, 1. and 2. algorithms are completely different... I got stuck during reverse enginnering, i am not a python guy.
- libmodes -> it does not even support situation when Q is 0...

What should be the proper way/algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never worked on ADSB, but I did on altimeters. Altimeters used binary data for large increments of altitude, such as 1000 feet. Gray code, also know as minimal change code was used for shorter increments. I n binary when going from 0111 to 1000, all four bits change, but they might not change at the same time. You might inadvertently ready 0000 in between 0111 and 1000. With gray code only 1 bit changes at a time. 0111 in gray code was 0100, 1000 in gray code was 1100. So only the MSB changed.

Comment: The gray code referenced might be Gillham Code - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillham_code